# How to track tweets?

Tags: twitter

TunnelBear offers 1 GB free every month when you tweet about them. I am trying to implement something like this in my web app.

This is how I intend to go about it.

- My system will let anyone tweet about my business with some predefined message like "Use Awesome_business to increase profit. Awesome_business is the best!"
- A cron job will regularly (every 5 min) fetch  the last 10 tweets of all connected twitter accounts
- Analyse them to see if they contains keywords like "use", "Awesome_business", "best", "increase", "profit"
- Offer discount for every account which tweets will contains keywords listed above.

Does anyone have a better idea about how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try leveraging Twitter's Streaming API: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis

So you can open a connection and you'll receive tweets as they occur, instead of having to periodically check (plus if there are more than 10 tweets in the last 5 min then you just lost those extras).

Also twitter's search API doesn't allow for specific times, you can only give it a day, so the best you could do is pull all tweets from the last day, and then manually parse the data to find tweets in the specific amount of time from your last poll.

Twitter's API also let's you do hashtag filtering, so you can just grab all tweets with a hashtag relevant to your business, and then reward those people specifically?  would make it easier on you so you don't have to write any parsing logic on your end.